# Javascript Populating An array by Value, with a async function

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous

I'm trying to populate an array, data comes in from async calls via promises.
However, at the end of the day my array either ends up empty, or its all the same value. (Somehow i think it's being populated by reference, instead of by value, even though i cloned it)

The console output shows 4 different versions of "v2", however the "totalFriendResults" array, only has 2 entries, both of which are the same.

I get the Values from V2 just fine, the problem is in populating totalFriendResutls. Am i doing something wrong in pushing to the array?

Any ideas on why this is happening?

```js
for(var count = 0; count< globalFriendsList.length; count++)
{
  inspectEachFriend(globalFriendsList[count]).then(function(v2)
  {
    console.log("this is v2",v2);
    var fix = new Object();
    fix = v2;
    var cloneMe = clone(v2);
    totalFriendResults.push(cloneMe)
  }
}
```

Comment: It is really impossible to help you with the code that is provided.

Comment: Also, if you insist on using tabs, please don't mix them with spaces. SO clearly uses a different tabstop than your editor. Also note that your code, as posted, will throw for the unmatched paren in your `.then` handler.

Comment: If you can use await/async, just define `function(v2)` as `async function(v2)`, and put `await` before the call to the asynchronous method. Assuming `clone(v2)` it would be `var cloneMe = await clone(v2);`

Answer (score 0):

I usually use `Promise.all()` for this kind of task

```
Promise.all(globalFriendsList.map(function(friend) {
    return inspectEachFriend(friend).then(function(v2) {
        console.log("this is v2",v2);
        var fix = new Object();
        fix = v2;
        var cloneMe = clone(v2);
        return cloneMe;
 })).then(function(totalFriendResults) {
     console.log(totalFriendResults) //--> array of cloneMe objects (not sure why you dont just return v2 ?!?)
 });
```

This is a demo:

```js
    var globalFriendsList = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

    function inspectEachFriend(friend) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var time = Math.random() * 1000;
            setTimeout(function() {
                resolve({"friendId" : friend, "waited" : time});
            }, time);
        });
    };

    Promise.all(globalFriendsList.map(inspectEachFriend))
        .then(function(totalFriendResults) {
           console.log(totalFriendResults) //--> array of inspectEachFriend() resolved objects
        }).catch(function(error) {
           console.error(error);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not approaching promises with the correct mindset. Think about what's happening in your code. Inside your loop, the following is happening:

1. Your promise runs
2. You wait until that promise resolves before pushing it into your array
3. The loop continues.

Your problem exists because you aren't controlling the order in which 2 and 3 finish (protip: 3 will almost always finish first). Your loop will continually run through itself before your promises resolve. Your promises resolve slower and your `i` will be the last value for `i` for all of the promises that finish. So here's how to fix it:

1. Use `let count = 0` instead of  `var count = 0`. This fixes your scoping issue because `count` will exist as its unique over each iteration.
2. You can't control each promise individually one by one. You start the promise and let it begin to run and then **control all of them at once with Promise.all`**

I run my promise and then push it into an array. It is running and is async. I iterate over all of the `globalFriendsList` and now my array `runningPromises` is an array full of running promises. Then those running promises I use `Promise.all` to ensure that all of the promises have resolved before moving on to the next lines of code.

I made a few changes to your code in this example.

```js
let promise1 = () => new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve('promise1 resolved'), 5000)
})

let promise2 = () => new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve('promise2 resolved'), 500)
})

let globalFriendsList = [promise1, promise2]
let runningPromises = []
for (let i=0; i < globalFriendsList.length; i++) {
  let promise = globalFriendsList[i]()
  .then((v2)=> {
    return v2
  })
  runningPromises.push(promise)
}

Promise.all(runningPromises)
.then((friendList) => {
  console.log(friendList)
})
```